# Circular dependency in configuring access policy of execute-api vpc endpoint to allow only specific API Gateway

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I need to create a private REST API which uses `execute-api` VPC endpoint to trigger lambdas. All the VPC endpoints are managed by cloud team in the organisation so they will create the endpoint for us and we will use it using data resource `aws_vpc_endpoint` of terraform.

We need rest api id in the VPC enpoint resource policy to allow only a specific API Gateway rest API.

```js
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123412341234:{rest_api_id}/*",
                "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123412341234:{rest_api_id}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and we need vpc enpoint id to create rest API:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "example" {
  name              = "example"
  put_rest_api_mode = "merge"

  endpoint_configuration {
    types            = ["PRIVATE"]
    vpc_endpoint_ids = [data.aws_vpc_endpoint.example.id]
  }
}
```

It looks like a circular dependency to me.

How should be handle this in our terraform code?

Comment: Have you actually tried running this code? Did it show any circular dependencies?

Comment: I couldn't try it out because the above code is in two different repositories, requiring IDs to proceed.